# Getting StoreException while accessing attendees calendar using Calendar Service(REST based)

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

Using Calendar service to access user's calendar in which he is attendee.

URL: `http://<host>/mail/test.nsf/api/calendar/events/4767DFD4B4A6B66488257E3F0043285F-Lotus_Auto_Generated.`

Getting the following exception if I am accepting that meeting using notes client. I am able to access that meeting without any errors using REST service.

```
{
  "code": 404,
  "text": "Not Found",
  "cserror": 1031,
  "message": "Error reading event",
  "type": "text",
  "data": "com.ibm.domino.calendar.store.StoreException: Error reading event
           at com.ibm.domino.calendar.dbstore.NotesCalendarStore.getEvent(NotesCalendarStore.java:185)
           at com.ibm.domino.services.calendar.resources.EventResource.getEventInternal(EventResource.java:604)
           at com.ibm.domino.services.calendar.resources.EventResource.getEvent(EventResource.java:137)
           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
           at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
           at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
           at ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The response to `GET /{database}/api/calendar/events` includes both events and notices.  An event is an entry that is already booked on the calendar (an appointment, a meeting, a reminder, etc.).  A notice is a separate document -- for example an invitation or a reschedule -- describing something about a meeting.  Technically, a notice is not booked on the calendar.

Here's an example of a notice in JSON format:

```
{
  "href": "/mail/dlawson.nsf/api/calendar/events/5BB9F2BCE41C33E185257E4200672A32-Lotus_Notes_Generated",
  "id": "5BB9F2BCE41C33E185257E4200672A32-Lotus_Notes_Generated",
  "summary": "Invitation: Quick update",
  "location": "My office",
  "start": {
    "date": "2015-05-15",
    "time": "17:00:00",
    "utc": true
  },
  "end": {
    "date": "2015-05-15",
    "time": "18:00:00",
    "utc": true
  },
  "class": "public",
  "transparency": "transparent",
  "sequence": 0,
  "x-lotus-organizer": {
    "data": "CN=Dean Melnyk/O=Peaks"
  },
  "x-lotus-summarydataonly": {
    "data": "TRUE"
  },
  "x-lotus-noticetype": {
    "data": "I"
  },
  "x-lotus-appttype": {
    "data": "3"
  },
  "x-lotus-unid": {
    "data": "5BB9F2BCE41C33E185257E4200672A32"
  }
}
```

The `x-lotus-notice` property indicates it is a notice -- in this case an invitation.

It's subtle, but I think the calendar API is returning 404 because you are attempting to read a notice with an event URL.  As you have discovered, you can't read the event until you have accepted the invitation.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Is there anyway i can access all the notices related to specific meeting whether it is accepted or not.